# Need File to be Virus Scanned before Upload to Azure?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

As a requirement we need to apply a virus scan to any content being uploaded to our application. Is the only Cloud based service that provide such functionality like malware and Virus Scan. All we need that service to provide api that accepts file data stream and return us the result after a scan.

We are using Asp.Net WebApi C# and Azure.

Comment: I think you should have a look at ClamAV https://www.clamav.net/

Comment: do we need to install that ??

Comment: You can host it in Azure. If the configuration is troublesome for you, a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/mailu/clamav/) would do the job for you. Various C# binding can then be found in GitHub (actually you can simply send requests to ClamAV in ReST flavour)

Comment: well i have no idea about docker. Can you send me the steps need to perform

Comment: You could easily install it in Ubuntu as well. I remember that APT can configure the needed services to e.g. updating the database.

Comment: is there any api that we can call directly without installing anything ?

Comment: There are, and I believe Google will then be a better place for this question. But be aware that a bunch of security and privacy issues are involved and since antivirus is a pretty computation intensive job I won't expect such services to come with a fair price.

Comment: @RaviMittal you can use trend-micro or any other saas solution for antivirus scanning, no installation - api's to do the scan and then there are others which gets files scanned from multiple antivirus providers in parallel

Comment: @tiona any example that you can share would be great.

Comment: have a look at [this one](https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/#getting-started), virus-total is free but you can also find paid ones if you want

Answer (score 0):

shame-less plug but you might want to check out https://scanii.com is a pure SaaS malware detection service that integrates nicely with Azure. Also, make sure you read Virus Total terms carefully since it cannot be used for commercial products (https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/public-api/).

Answer (score 0):

This approach works really well and allows you to block viruses and malware, but also other threats such as scripts, executables, and invalid files:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Cloudmersive.APIClient.NETCore.VirusScan.Api;
using Cloudmersive.APIClient.NETCore.VirusScan.Client;
using Cloudmersive.APIClient.NETCore.VirusScan.Model;

namespace Example
{
    public class ScanFileAdvancedExample
    {
        public void main()
        {
            // Configure API key authorization: Apikey
            Configuration.Default.AddApiKey("Apikey", "YOUR_API_KEY");
            
            

            var apiInstance = new ScanApi();
            var inputFile = new System.IO.FileStream("C:\\temp\\inputfile", System.IO.FileMode.Open); // System.IO.Stream | Input file to perform the operation on.
            var allowExecutables = false;  // bool? | Set to false to block executable files (program code) from being allowed in the input file.  Default is false (recommended). (optional) 
            var allowInvalidFiles = false;  // bool? | Set to false to block invalid files, such as a PDF file that is not really a valid PDF file, or a Word Document that is not a valid Word Document.  Default is false (recommended). (optional) 
            var allowScripts = false;  // bool? | Set to false to block script files, such as a PHP files, Pythong scripts, and other malicious content or security threats that can be embedded in the file.  Set to true to allow these file types.  Default is false (recommended). (optional) 
            var allowPasswordProtectedFiles = false;  // bool? | Set to false to block password protected and encrypted files, such as encrypted zip and rar files, and other files that seek to circumvent scanning through passwords.  Set to true to allow these file types.  Default is false (recommended). (optional) 
            var restrictFileTypes = "";  // string | Specify a restricted set of file formats to allow as clean as a comma-separated list of file formats, such as .pdf,.docx,.png would allow only PDF, PNG and Word document files.  All files must pass content verification against this list of file formats, if they do not, then the result will be returned as CleanResult=false.  Set restrictFileTypes parameter to null or empty string to disable; default is disabled. (optional) 

            try
            {
                // Advanced Scan a file for viruses
                VirusScanAdvancedResult result = apiInstance.ScanFileAdvanced(inputFile, allowExecutables, allowInvalidFiles, allowScripts, allowPasswordProtectedFiles, restrictFileTypes);
                Debug.WriteLine(result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Print("Exception when calling ScanApi.ScanFileAdvanced: " + e.Message );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You will need to install this Nuget package:

```
Install-Package Cloudmersive.APIClient.NETCore.VirusScan -Version 2.0.3
```

Nuget package is open source.  API key is free for 1,000 scans/month.

Hope this helps!